# Taylor Expansion of a Trig Function

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

Did a problem in a lecture today with Taylor Expansions.

The question is:

Find the Taylor Expansion of 
$
z=\sin(x^2+y^2)
$
To the second order at the point (1, -1)

I am happy with the solution until she gets to 
$
\frac{d^2(f)}{d(y)^2}(1,-1)=-4\sin(2)=-3,637
$

According to my own calculations,
$
\frac{d^2(f)}{d(y)^2}(1,-1)=2\cos(2)-4\sin(2)=-4,469
$

She checked her answers and insists that she is correct. I am confused as to where that $2\cos(2)$ went. If someone could explain it to me that would be awesome.

---

$
\frac {df}{dy}=2y\cos (x^2+y^2)
$

And
$
\frac {d^2(f)}{d(y)^2}=2\cos(x^2+y^2)-4(y)^2 \sin(x^2+y^2)
$

(Using product rule)

Comment: I am amazed by your teacher's self confidence, but I think she's wrong here, because Wolfram Alpha is never wrong (and I'm rarely wrong), and both of us say you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are fine. We have
$$
f(x,y):=\sin(x^2+y^2)
$$ giving by the chain rule
$$
\frac {df}{dy}(x,y)=2y\cos (x^2+y^2), \qquad \frac {d^2f}{d^2y}(x,y)=2\cos(x^2+y^2)-4y^2 \sin(x^2+y^2)
$$ and

> $$
> \left.\frac {d^2f}{d^2y}(x,y)\right|_{(1,-1)}=2\cos(2)-4 \sin(2)=-4.469483380\cdots.
> $$

Comment: Thank you, I will apprach her in our next lecture.

Answer (score 1):

If that is indeed the calculation that you are both trying to execute (perhaps this is where the misunderstanding lies?), then you are right.

Comment: I don't care enough about it to pursue it, but if there is *some* subterm of the overall calculation which involves (approximately) −3,637 then your parenthetical is spot-on.